# Proper Notation/Logic for Showing a Relation is a Function

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working with relations that I want to show are functions. I know the general algorithm for doing this for some $f : A \rightarrow B$ , i.e, show:

1. $f \subseteq A \times B$
2. $ \forall a \in A \,\exists b \in B  \,((a,b) \in f) $
3. $(a,x) \in f  \land (a,y)\in f \implies x=y $

My question is about how to show condition 3 properly, i.e, without using the notation $f(a)$. It seems that since we don't know what $f(a)$ is here that it would be difficult to show condition 3. I tried to do this for the function $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$, but couldn't avoid the issue I'm referring to. I appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: I prefer to think of relations in infix notation: instead of $(a,b) \in f$, I prefer to use the symbol $\sim$ and write $a \sim b$.

Then your axioms become:

1. $\mathrm{Graph}(\sim) \subseteq A \times B$. ("The relation has the right "domain" and "codomain".)
2. For all $a \in A$, there is $b \in B$ such that $a \sim b$. ("Everything in the domain has a relative".)
3. If $a \sim x$ and $a \sim y$, then $x = y$. ("There's at most one thing related to $a$".)

Comment: Right, I understand the logic of the idea, I'm just having trouble with the notation for condition 3. I'm trying to get everything straight so I can show this for specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

> 2. and 3. together can be read as 
>      $\forall a\in A\ .\ |\{b\in B:(a,b)\in f\}|=1$

i.e. that there *is* (2.) and there is *at most one* (3.) image $b\in B$ along the *relation* $f$ for each $a\in A$.

For the specific example $f:x\mapsto x^2$, we have the $(x,x^2)$ pairs for all $x\in\Bbb R$ as elements of $\ f$, *as a relation*.
And indeed, any number $a\in\Bbb R$ appears exactly once on the left side of a pair within $f$.